# How to forecast individual customer's spend (for millions of customers)?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, exponential-smoothing, business-intelligence

Which forecasting model fits better to forecast the customers spend in the next upcoming visit? We have millions of customers, so ARIMA or any other time series modeling for each of the customers is not feasible (computationally).

Built Linear model (using a different level of moving average terms and other independent variables) and the average model (average spend per visit in the last X visits or time period). The performance of the linear model is similar to that of average model. How can I improve the linear model or build a better forecasting model?

```
Sample data:
Customer    Visit Date  Spend
1           1/21/2018   302
2           1/21/2018   308
3           1/23/2018   2112
4           1/35/2018   123
1           2/14/2018   234
1           2/16/2018   534
2           3/4/2018    1254
3           6/6/2018    854
1           6/2/2018    150
1           6/8/2018    720
2           9/9/2018    440
4           12/12/2018  323
3           12/15/2018  445
1           12/16/2018  660
1           as_of_today ?
2           as_of_today ?
3           as_of_today ?
4           as_of_today ?
```

Edit on  2019-01-31:
I am not looking to forecast individually for each of the customers. I did segment the customers and built the linear models for each segment. However, want to build a better model than a linear model. So looking if there are any better forecasting techniques that can help me.

Comment: Do you really need individual forecast for each one of the millions of customers? For what purpose will these forecast be used? Maybe start with segmentation, time-series clustering, ... and then maybe individual forecasts for only the most important?

Comment: I am not looking to forecast individually for each of the customers. I did segment the customers and built the linear models for each segment. However, want to build a better model than a linear model. So looking if there are any better forecasting techniques that can help me.

Comment: Please add this new information as an edit to the OP (original post). But without more details I doubt anybody will have much to say

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Are you interested in *when* the customer will return, *how much* the individual will spend, or both?

Comment: @DemetriPananos I am interested only in how much will the customer spend.

Comment: @ML101  Try a hierarchical gamma regression model